# PowerShell Workflow do...while loop..looped

Tags: powershell, workflow

I am tinkering with Workflows to process concurrently many files. I have written a (shitty) piece of code prior to the actual implementation.

The problem is the loop..is looped!. The idea of the script is to get a list of files onto an Array, (lets call it "Original") create new arrays (lets call them "LoopingArray") to process the files in batches of "x" files and remove the processed items form the array to create a new array to process..etc, until the original Array is empty.

For each item a txt file is created, so when the "Original" array is empty, the Do..While should stop. But it doesn't. it keeps creating files over and over. What I am doing wrong?:

```
   Workflow Test-Workflow {
      $SourceFolder = "c:\test\whatever"
      $Files = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($SourceFolder, '*.*', 'AllDirectories')
      $ArrayCount = $Files| Measure-Object | Select-Object Count

    Do {

        $NewArray = $Files | Select-Object -First 20
        $Files = $Files | Where-Object { $NewArray -notcontains $_ }
        $ArrayCount = $Files| Measure-Object | Select-Object Count

        ForEach -Parallel ($it in $NewArray)
            {

                $Name = Get-Random
                $Filepath = "C:\temp\test\"+"$Name"+".txt"
                $it | Out-File -FilePath $Filepath

            }
    } Until ($ArrayCount.Count -eq "0")

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: workflows are known to be odd ... and the sequence of operations is apparently not assured. however, the problem may be that you are comparing a numeric string to an actual _number_. while PoSh otta coerce the `"0"` from a `[string]` to an `[int]`, a workflow may glitch that. have you tried using a proper `($ArrayCount.Count -eq 0)`? note the lack of quotes around the zero.

Comment: also, is there a reason to use a workflow [not really totally powershell, just kinda-sorta] instead of jobs or one of the parallelism cmdlets/modules like `PoshRSJob`?

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey- Setting the [string] to [int] causes the same effect. In response to why I chose Workflows: I had to process a really HUGE folder with millions of files and set the ACLS properly. The whole process could take like 14 days non-stop with my initial script. Someone suggested to use the Foreach -parallel supported by PS core and though it made wonders, it only reduced the time by half. So I am tinkering with all sort of parallel processing feature to find which one could reduce the whole process to just 2 days (48 hours) which is my maintenance window. I will take a look on PSJobs.

Comment: thanks for the info. [*grin*] ///// there is a known gotcha with powershell objects that ought to get more than one item ... but only get one. the `.Count` property can sometimes return `0` instead of `1`. the usual fix is to wrap the command in `@()`, or to use `[array]` in front of the holder $Var to force it to be an array even if only one item was returned. you may want to try that.

Comment: i would avoid workflows unless you KNOW that you need what they give. they are only kinda-sorta powershell and are known to have many oddities. plus, they are not supported in the newer versions of PoSh [v6 & v7] - and almost certainly will not be supported..

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey, many thanks! I will avoid them then and focus on the Foreach -parallel from Posh and take a look atthe jobs..I may be able to distribute the workload between different servers running powershell...my idea is to run the script from one server, distribute the values of the arrays containing all files and folders to be modified between 2-3 servers and let them do the job - I know that the folders have to be treated first and not in parallel as the inheritance can get pretty fckd up. What do you think?

Comment: you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// splitting your work across several systems may mean that your actions on the filesystem would be run remotely - system_A working on the filesystem on system_B. if that happens, you will see a large slowdown. try to keep the code running on  the  system where the files are _if you can_.